# Force.com IDE problem after import visibility issue, set field-level security

Tags: ide, fields

I guess after exporting Custom Fields and importing to a NEW Dev the fields shows but they are all invisible have to be reactivated from Set Field-Level Security.

Anyway around this?

Answer (score 1):

You can include profiles and permission sets in the metadata that is pulled from an org and pushed into another org by the Force.com IDE so that `fieldLevelSecurities` elements are automatically set.

Add this to your package.xml:

```
<types>
    <members>Admin</members>
    <members>Some Other Profile Name</members>
    <name>Profile</name>
</types>
```

where the "System Adminstrator" profile is unexpectedly named "Admin".

For permission sets its `PermissionSet` in place of `Profile`. See the [Metadata API Developer’s
Guide](https://resources.docs.salesforce.com/sfdc/pdf/api_meta.pdf) for detail.